# Razor is emitting the wrong value into a hidden field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am dealing with some aberrant behavior in with the razor engine. I have the following code in a my razor view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCabinetItem", "Builder"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LibraryItemID)
    ...
```

The value of model is as follows:

```
Model = new CabinetItem {
    ID = 0,
    LibraryItemID = 155,
    ...
}
```

I verified that these values are correct in debug on the razor view itself. The HTML that is emitted is wrong:

```
<input data-val="true" ... id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="155">
<input data-val="true" ... id="LibraryItemID" name="LibraryItemID" type="hidden" value="155">
```

Razor emitted 155 into both hidden fields. What is going on here? I'm not doing any in javascript with these fields. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I'm working with MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2013.

**Here is the definition for CabinetItem**

```
public abstract class JobItem : IEquatable<JobItem>
{
    protected JobItem()
    {

    }

    protected JobItem(LibraryItem a_item)
    {
        #region Argument Validation

        if (a_item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("a_item");

        #endregion

        LibraryItemID = a_item.WizardLibraryItemId;
        Name = a_item.Name;

        Quantity = 1;
    }

    protected JobItem(JobItem a_other)
    {
        #region Argument Validation

        if (a_other == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("a_other");

        #endregion

        ID = a_other.ID;
        LibraryItemID = a_other.LibraryItemID;
        Name = a_other.Name;

        Quantity = a_other.Quantity;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int LibraryItemID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(CutReady.Web.Languages.Builder.Builder), Name = "QuantityLabel")]
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CutReady.Web.Languages.Builder.Builder), ErrorMessageResourceName = "QuantityRangeError")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public abstract JobItem Clone();

    public override bool Equals(object a_obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, a_obj)) 
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, a_obj)) 
            return true;

        if (a_obj.GetType() != typeof (JobItem)) 
            return false;

        return Equals((JobItem) a_obj);
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(JobItem a_other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, a_other)) 
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, a_other)) 
            return true;

        return LibraryItemID == a_other.LibraryItemID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return LibraryItemID;
    }

}

public class CabinetItem : JobItem
{
    public CabinetItem()
    {

    }

    public CabinetItem(LibraryItem a_item)
        : base (a_item)
    {
        #region Argument Validation

        if (a_item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("a_item");

        #endregion

        ItemWidth = a_item.ItemWidth;
        ItemDepth = a_item.ItemDepth;
        ItemHeight = a_item.ItemHeight;
        ItemWidthLock = new DimensionLock(a_item.ItemMinWidth, a_item.ItemMaxWidth);
        ItemHeightLock = new DimensionLock(a_item.ItemMinHeight, a_item.ItemMaxHeight);
        ItemDepthLock = new DimensionLock(a_item.ItemMinDepth, a_item.ItemMaxDepth);
    }

    public CabinetItem(CabinetItem a_other)
        : base(a_other)
    {
        #region Argument Validation

        if (a_other == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("a_cabinet");

        #endregion

        ItemWidth = a_other.ItemWidth;
        ItemDepth = a_other.ItemDepth;
        ItemHeight = a_other.ItemHeight;
        ItemWidthLock = new DimensionLock(a_other.ItemWidthLock.Minimum, a_other.ItemWidthLock.Maximum);
        ItemHeightLock = new DimensionLock(a_other.ItemHeightLock.Minimum, a_other.ItemHeightLock.Maximum);
        ItemDepthLock = new DimensionLock(a_other.ItemDepthLock.Minimum, a_other.ItemDepthLock.Maximum);
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(CutReady.Web.Languages.Builder.Builder), Name = "WidthLabel")]
    public double ItemWidth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(CutReady.Web.Languages.Builder.Builder), Name = "HeightLabel")]
    public double ItemHeight { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(CutReady.Web.Languages.Builder.Builder), Name = "DepthLabel")]
    public double ItemDepth { get; set; }

    public DimensionLock ItemWidthLock { get; set; }
    public DimensionLock ItemHeightLock { get; set; }
    public DimensionLock ItemDepthLock { get; set; }

    public override JobItem Clone()
    {
        return new CabinetItem(this);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object a_obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, a_obj)) 
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, a_obj)) 
            return true;

        if (a_obj.GetType() != typeof (CabinetItem)) 
            return false;

        return Equals((CabinetItem) a_obj);
    }

    public override bool Equals(JobItem other)
    {
        var cabinet = other as CabinetItem;

        if (cabinet == null)
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, cabinet)) 
            return true;

        if (!base.Equals(cabinet))
            return false;

        if (!ItemWidth.Equals(cabinet.ItemWidth))
            return false;

        if (!ItemHeight.Equals(cabinet.ItemHeight))
            return false;

        if (!ItemDepth.Equals(cabinet.ItemDepth))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hashCode = base.GetHashCode();

            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ ItemWidth.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ ItemHeight.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ ItemDepth.GetHashCode();

            return hashCode;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You've probably already done this, but step through the model creation code to make sure ID is 0 and not being set to 155 due to hidden code (incorrect setter etc).

Comment: That was the first thing that I did. `HiddenFor` takes a lambda expression and it is impossible to see what _that_ value is. You cannot breakpoint a lambda in a razor view. But I assume that `HiddenFor` is using the same object as the `Model` property and the values on that are correct.

Comment: Please show the definition for CabinetItem, in particular the implementation/declaration of `ID` and `LibraryItemID`, most likely one of them is incorrectly written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only logical explanation for this behavior is that you've got something in the view data that's overriding the value from the property. If any of the following exist with a value of 155, that value will be used instead:

- `ViewBag.ID`
- `ViewData["ID"]`
- `Request["ID"]`

Also, remember that these are all case-insensitive, i.e. `ViewBag.id` would also be used to fill the value.

Comment: Why would it do that? That is counter intuitive behavior. My issue is that the controller call had an 'id' parameter because that is what I am using in my routing. I create an object and send it in the response. So because it was a post, razor ignored my objects value and used the routing argument instead. I guess I'll switch over to get. No secure data in this request. I still don't understand why that behavior is there.

Comment: It's because 99% of the time, you *would* want this behavior. I admit, it's not overly intuitive when problems like this occur, but it gives you a lot of flexibility you wouldn't have otherwise.

Comment: Switching to get didn't change anything.

Comment: Also, if the id is a request param, it doesn't matter if the method is GET or POST: the same behavior will occur. What you should do is match up your names. If the `id` in the request refers actually to a `LibraryItem` and not the object you're editing, then you should really have your action parameter be named something like `libraryItemId`. Then, you wouldn't have this issue. That also makes it more intuitive as to what the parameter is for.

Comment: That messes with my routing. I found another alternative that seems a lot more elegant. I added this line to the top of my controller action: `this.ModelState.Remove("id")`

Comment: True, but shoe-horning your application logic to fit an arbitrary routing scheme is not exactly good design. If you find the default routing system too confining (I did too), you can try attribute routing. It's supported out of the box in MVC 5+ and can be added to previous versions via the AttributeRouting Nuget package. Gives you much more flexibility with your routes.